# which appium java-client is used to test android oreo?

Tags: appium, appium-android, java-client

I am trying to automate android oreo using appium..

My framework is built on java-client 2.x.. can I use same with android O and uiautomator2? which is the least version of appium java-client required to automate it?

Comment: The latest version is always the most stable that you can find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi It is always best practice to use latest [java-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.0.0-BETA4)

Comment: But then my methods which are removed in a newer version will not be used anymore.

Comment: See, the methods you are using those are deprecated, you have to use new methods.

Comment: That's why I asked. I need to change framework code, right?

Comment: yes, you have to check the newly added methods, and you replace deprecated methods with the new ones.